# How do I use Generic type in method as the returned type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

How would I return an integer as shown below?

```
    public T Test<T>()
    {   
        //return 999;
        //return (RT)999;
        //return 999 as RT;
    }
```

None of those returns work, they are all complaining about not being able to be of or converted to that generic type.  How do I inject the type to return so that design time doesn't complain?

Of course this works but must always return an integer.  I don't want to always return an integer and I don't want to return type of object.

```
    public int Test()
    {
        return 999;       
    }
```

3/15/2015 This question was put on hold due to opinion that the question was not clear...  How is this question not clear?

Comment: Presumably you don't always want to return 999 either?

Comment: You can start with `return default(RT);` but I sense there is more to the story of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public RT Test<RT>()
{
    object value = 999;
    return (RT)value;
}
```

Comment: You can simplify it down to the ugly `return (RT)(object)999;`.

Comment: We can't just simplify it.  That function could be doing work to get the number 999 or (not illustrated in the example) as string of "What am I doing".

Comment: I really wouldn't call this a "double Cast".  There is a code smell here indicating something isn't right.  What does Test() do?  Does it always return a number?  Who is calling Test()?  They already know the type they expect so why not have them do the work of casting it?  Something seems off about doing this, but I don't know the full context of what is going on so I can't really comment much more about if this is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you want the method to actually accomplish, how about something like this...

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = -8;
    int j = MyGenericMethod<int>(i);

    string s = MyGenericMethod<string>("Testing");
}

private T MyGenericMethod<T>(T input)
{
    // Do something to input

    return input;
}
```

Or you could pass input as a reference parameter and not need the return type.